door chime system with normally closed contacts?
I need a standard doorbell (16VAC) that works with magnetic reed switches mounted on front and back doors. These switches are closed when the door is closed and open up when the door opens (magnet swings away). This is the opposite of normal doorbell switches, which are normally open and close momentarily to sound the chime. I can reverse the state of the door contacts with little 24v relays or even use a Raspberry PI to generate a dry closure but I don't want to over-complicate the project with all these parts that can fail!
Anyone know of a chime that works with NC contacts instead of NO?

Aside: Depending on the physical arrangement you may be able to add a separate magnet to provide a bias field that closes the reed switch. With the right polarity and placement of the bias magnet the magnet mounted on the door will cancel the field and allow the reed switch to open.

Other aside: Doorbells aren't usually 100% duty cycle devices. If a door is left open for a long time the doorbell or transformer may trip a thermal protective device and opt out for a few minutes until it cools off. If you add a relay to flip the NO/NC state you can use a time-delay relay that will only stay on for a brief period, so you'll get the dong to go with your ding.

You need to install "normally closed" reed switches.
These are available in almost all the form factors as the normally open type (that you seem to have). You have to shop at a serious electrical supply house, as big-box stores cannot afford to stock enough variations of magnetic switches.
You may find the form you need only as a "double throw", or SPDT type. These can be used as "normally closed" types by ignoring one of the terminal wires.
